# How to eliminate the coefficient of $x$ and $y$ from the equation of an ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

I am on my way of converting the ellipse $ Q(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + 2fy + 2gx+c$ to its more friendly form $S(X^\prime, Y^\prime)  = \dfrac{X{{^\prime}^2} }{\alpha'^2} + \dfrac{Y{{^\prime}^2} }{\beta'^2} - 1 = 0$.

I know how to eliminate the term $xy$, by rotating the axes by $\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2h}{a-b}$.

But before that rotation, we need to translate the axes so as to eliminate the $x$ and $y$ terms first. I came across this method:

**Compute $c'=\frac{\Delta}{\delta}$**, where $\delta =\begin{vmatrix} a & h \\ h & b\end{vmatrix}$ and $\Delta = \begin{vmatrix} a & h & g \\ h & b & f \\ g & f & c \end{vmatrix}$.

So, the new equation is ${R(X,Y) = Q(X + u, Y + v)} = aX^2 + b Y^2 + 2hXY + c^\prime$, where $(u, v)$ is the center of the conic, and is given by $\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}  = 0 \\ \dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y}  = 0 \end{cases}$.

**My question**: What if the proof/reasoning behind  $c'=\frac{\Delta}{\delta}$? How does it so easily replace the $c$, and then we can drop the $x$ and $y$ terms. Why does it work?

Comment: Compute $u$ and $v$, then replace $x$ and $y$, respectively, in the original equation with $X+u$ and $Y+v$ and see what you get.

Comment: @amd I understand, I would get back the same result as I have described. But I still wonder why $c'$ magically has such a beautiful value of $\Delta/\delta$ :/ For a comparison, the values of $u$ and $v$ have weird terms like $ag-bf$ and $bf-ch$ :(

Comment: Not that weird, if you ask me. The homogeneous coordinates of the center are the last row/column of the inverse matrix, so you’re going to see various minors of it.